# Number of smooth structures on a compact manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm new to this field: is there a compact smooth manifold of dimension $n\geq 5$ with uncountably many smooth structures no two of which are diffeomorphic. This is motivated by Milnor's exotic sphere $\mathbb{S}^7$, but I've read that there are only $15$ diffeomorphism classes for Milnor's sphere.

Comment: Do you know an example for $n=4$?

Comment: There are only countably many diffeomorphism classes of compact smooth manifolds.

Comment: @AndyPutman, is there a easy proof of the result you mention, or refference?

Comment: Yes, thanks katago, any references or proofs are welcome. Arbitrary statements to be taken on account of faith or authority do not qualify of course haha...@SamHopkins No I don't but I believe the above statement has been proved for $\mathbb{R^4}$ (although not compact of course) by Donaldson and Freedman as mentionned in Lee's intro to manifolds book, that's why I wrote $n\geq 5$, to weed out anything else....

Comment: @RachidAtmai: That's an unnecessarily aggressive way of asking for more details.  What's trivial is that there are countably many compact triangulated manifolds. In dimensions up to 4, PL structures and smooth structures coincide. In higher dimensions, smoothing theory shows that a compact PL manifold admits finitely many smoothings.  But you can do better, e.g. by showing that there are only finitely many manifolds with sufficient bounds on their geometry like in 
Grove, K, Petersen, P, Wu, J,
Geometric finiteness theorems via controlled topology. 
Invent. Math. 99 (1990), no. 1, 205–213.

Comment: @AndyPutman Hey sorry for being snappy my man ;) and thanks for the extra details!

Comment: Dear @RachidAtmai : It is also inappropriate to refer to Professor Putman as "my man."